# How to make Azure Pipelines yaml trigger branch with specific project?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have this project repo on Github and the repo has many project in it.

So in my scenario its like this.

api-build-pipeline
project-1: trigger branch-1
ui-build-pipiline
project-2: trigger branch-1

So if I only have an update on project-1 the project-2 should not be triggered but I don't know how to do that if their trigger is the same branch.

I want the trigger something like this
trigger: - branch-1 ..project-1

Is that possible? I don't want them use different branches if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the trigger to exclude or include paths to trigger the build only when a file from that project is changed.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - branch1
  paths:
    include:
    - project1
    exclude:
    - project2
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths